# Decorating ng-click inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to decorate the `ngClickDirective` in order to add a custom listener. This code works fine on `ng-click`s which are not nested inside of `ng-repeat`:

```
$provide.decorator('ngClickDirective', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
    var original = $delegate[0].compile;
    $delegate[0].compile = function(element, attrs, transclude) {
        element.bind('click', function() {
            console.log('Tracking this');
        });
        return original(element, attrs, transclude);
    };
    return $delegate;
}]);
```

Is there any way to make this `bind` work when `ng-click` is nested inside of `ng-repeat`?

Simple plnkr to show the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/hEkBHG7pcJfoXff523Yl?p=preview

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For performance reason, the `ng-repeat` will compile only the original element once. Then just clone the element and do the linking for each item in the collection.

Therefore, you have to add a custom listener at `link:` function instead of `compile:` like this:

```
$provide.decorator('ngClickDirective', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
    var originalCompile = $delegate[0].compile;
    $delegate[0].compile = function() {
        var originalLink = originalCompile.apply(this, arguments);

        return function postLink(scope, element, attr) {
          element.bind('click', function() {
              alert('hello!');
          });

          return originalLink.apply(this, arguments);
        };
    };
    return $delegate;
}]);
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/aGbB5LuJNtdL9JXtwNSV?p=preview

Comment: Oh yes, thank you. I didn't realise `compile` is only called once per ng-repeat, thank you! :)